# Remove dollar sign at beginning of line

Tags: display, line-truncation

In emacs when I scroll right and beginning of lines are truncated emacs inserts dollar sign same as it insert \ at the end of truncated line. I wish it would not insert these two signs. Can I disable this behavior?

Comment: In which mode are you? (This appears in the grey line before last line.)

Comment: [Not an answer but... ] tried M-x visual-line-mode ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking how to turn off such line truncation? If so, the answer is `M-x toggle-truncate-lines`.

You can also set variable `truncate-lines` to `nil` in any given buffer. And you can set its default, global value using `setq-default`.

See the Emacs manual, node [Line Truncation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Line-Truncation.html).

See also user option `truncate-partial-width-windows`.

---

You could discover this using command `apropos-command` or `apropos` with keyword `truncate`.

---

If you instead are asking how to change the chars used, `$` and `\`, or how to have no chars indicate that truncation is in effect, I think the answer is that you cannot - that's coded in C source code.

Comment: To the extent that line truncation symbols appear in the `fringe` of a GUI version of Emacs, the symbols can be changed to another bitmap or eliminated using the `fringe-indicator-alist` with the cons-cell `car` of `truncation` / `continuation` and the `cdr` containing the bitmaps (another cons-cell for left/right indicators).

Comment: @lawlist I feel like I need PHD to configure emacs.

Comment: @Drew $ and \ are not hardcoded. When I enable fringe they dissapear but I don't want to see fringe either.

Comment: If you think they're not coded in C then use or modify the Lisp code that you think they're coded in.

Comment: @Drew I would but $ and \ are distracting me

Answer (score 0):

What you're referring to is described in the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Line-Truncation.html#Line-Truncation):

> As an alternative to continuation (*note Continuation Lines::), Emacs
>   can display long lines by “truncation”.  This means that all the
>   characters that do not fit in the width of the screen or window do not
>   appear at all.  On graphical displays, a small straight arrow in the
>   fringe indicates truncation at either end of the line.  On text
>   terminals, this is indicated with ‘$’ signs in the rightmost and/or
>   leftmost columns.

It turns out this can be customized through the use of variable `buffer-display-table` whose docstring includes:

> Display table that controls display of the contents of current buffer.
>
> ...
>
> If this variable is nil, the value of ‘standard-display-table’ is used.
>
> ...
>
> In addition, a char-table has six extra slots to control the display of:
>
> the end of a truncated screen line (extra-slot 0, a single character);
>
> the end of a continued line (extra-slot 1, a single character);
>
> the escape character used to display character codes in octal
>       (extra-slot 2, a single character);
>
> ...
>
> See also the functions ‘display-table-slot’ and ‘set-display-table-slot’.

We follow the trail to the docstring of `set-display-table-slot`:

> (set-display-table-slot DISPLAY-TABLE SLOT VALUE)
>
> Set the value of the extra slot in DISPLAY-TABLE named SLOT to VALUE.
>   SLOT may be a number from 0 to 5 inclusive, or a name (symbol).
>   Valid symbols are ‘truncation’, ‘wrap’, ‘escape’, ‘control’,
>   ‘selective-display’, and ‘vertical-border’.

So finally... If you haven't defined `buffer-display-table` you should set the `truncation` slot of `standard-display-table` to the wanted char, eg 32 for a space.  To do so, you can add the following to your init file:

```el
(set-display-table-slot standard-display-table 'truncation 32)
```